# What is the Dword vaule to to leave mail on the server for outlook

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, windows-registry, pop3

I am creating a ms registry file to setup an email account in outlook. I would like to have the users use pop3 and use the option to leave the mail on the server. What is the correct dword  value to use for that in ms registry?

Example:

```
"Leave Mail On Server"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Why not set up one client the way you want it and then export and/or look at the registry entries and values that got set?

Comment: Why not use IMAP where "leave on server" is the default *and* properly works with multiple machines?

Comment: @grawity Software app communicates via POP3 not IMAP is why I am using POP3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost all cases with the registry, if it's a Boolean (True/False, Yes/No) setting, then it'd be "1" to enable it (true),  or "0" to disable (false).

Comment: So for the value to leave on server would be "Leave Mail On Server"=dword:00000001? The reason I ask is because the value for connection type is :  "Connection Type"=dword:00000003

Comment: "Connection Type" won't be a yes/no (boolean) setting.